# “does not contain a definition for ...and no extension method ...accepting a first argument for type error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following error:

```
'DirectActivity' does not contain a definition for 'ddl_jobcode_Id2' and no extension method 'ddl_jobcode_Id2' accepting a first argument of type 'DirectActivity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

In my aspx, I created a DropDownList like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_jobcode_Id2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddl_ActivityType2"
                            DataTextField="jobCode" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("jobCode_ID2", "{0}") %>'
                            OnDataBound="ddl_jobcode_Id2_DataBound" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddl_jobcode_Id2_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
                            AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I need to add a control so that in the .cs file I worte

```
protected void ddl_jobcode_Id2_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.ddl_jobcode_Id2.SelectedValue == "19" )
     {  ...}}
```

and it just shows this error on `ddl_jobcode_Id2`

could anyone help me please? many thanks!!!

Comment: Have you changed the classes at the page directives section (that first line on your .aspx file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you're binding a value to your `SelectedValue` property. This probably means you have this `DropDownList` in some `Template` of a data control. 
In that case you'll need to set a handler for an event of your data control where your template has been instatiated (I can't tell without knowing the exact control), and `FindControl`(`"ddl_jobcode_Id2"`) your way to your `DropDownList` in code-behind.